# HTTP_COOKIE RewriteCond Failing

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, cookies

I have the following `Rewrite` code in my Apache config file but I can't get it to recognize when the cookie is present.  I've looked a bunch of answers on here but can't seem to find one that fixes whatever issue I'm running into.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} ^returnvisitor$ [NC]
RewriteRule .? - [S=3]
RewriteRule /index.html /new_visitor.html
RewriteRule .* - [CO=returnvisitor:yes:.127.0.0.1:1440:/:true:true]
RewriteRule .? - [S=1]
RewriteRule /index.html /returning_visitor.html
```

Update 1:

I've modified the code as follows and made some progress, but still doesn't act as it should.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} returnvisitor=yes [NC]
RewriteRule .? - [S=3]
RewriteRule /index.html /new_visitor.html [R]
RewriteRule .* - [CO=returnvisitor:yes:.127.0.0.1:1440:/:true:true]
RewriteRule .? - [S=1]
RewriteRule /index.html /returning_visitor.html [R,L]
```

The original code would redirect the homepage (i.e. the default page being `index.html`) however, now I have to manual request `index.html` in the url for the redirect to trigger, but at least this time on the second request of `index.html` I'm redirected to `returning_visitor.html`.

I need the redirects to occur when accessing the hompage via `example.com` for the first time the visitor is sent to `new_visitor.html` and subsequent visits are redirected to `returning_visitor.html`.  With out having to manual enter `example.com/index.html`.

Comment: is your cookie just a name, no value? try `^returnvisitor=` instead?

Comment: @MarcB I'm creating the cookie for the first time with the `RewriteRule .* - [CO=returnvisitor:yes:.127.0.0.1:1440:/:true:true]` line of code.  I check my browser and cookie is being created properly, it's just not being detected in `RewriteCond`.  I did try that condition as well as `/^(.*;)?returnvisitor=yes(;*.)?$/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use :

```
RewriteEngine on
#First visit
# if the cookie is not set
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !returnvisitor=yes$ [NC]
# serve "/new_visitor.html" 
RewriteRule /index.html /new_visitor.html [R,L]
#second visit
#set the cookie "returnvisitor" on any uri
RewriteRule .* - [CO=returnvisitor:yes:.127.0.0.1:1440:/:true:true]
#check to see that the cookie is set
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} returnvisitor=yes$ [NC]    
#if so, redirect the index.html to "/returning_visitor.html" 
RewriteRule /index.html /returning_visitor.html [R,L]
```

Let me know how it works for you.